# Build complex condition in projection of mongo query

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

In my query, I have got data like

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "prods": [
    {
      "consider": true,
      "recom": true
    },
    {
      "consider": true,
      "recom": false
    },
    {
      "consider": false,
      "recom": false
    }
  ]
}
```

In projection, I want to add a field like main_recom: true/false

**true** if all **consider** value which is true has **recom** as true as well.

**flase** if all **consider** which is true has any **recom** as false or if all **consider** value is false.

Programatically

```
main_recom = false

foreach prod of prods
 if prod.consider = true:
  
    if prod.recom = true:
     main_recom = true

    if prod.recom = false:
      main_recom = false
      break; // break loop
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation operators,

- `$concatArrays` to concat both the property's value in a single array
- `$allElementsTrue` to check if the above array has all values true then return true otherwise false

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      main_recom: {
        $allElementsTrue: {
          $concatArrays: ["$prods.consider", "$prods.recom"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ucAX-pfuHdr)

Comment: Can it be done as part of projection?

Comment: yes, you can use it in projection.

Comment: But if $prods.consider is false, i should not check recom value at all. Only if value of consider is true recom should be checked..

Comment: So what should be the result if `$prods.consider is false`?

Comment: If "consider" is false ignore the array element. If "consider" is true check if "recom" is true. Only if all "consider" having true also has "recom" as true set flag as true.

Comment: *If "consider" is false ignore the array element.* => means you don't need that `main_recom` property in projection? I am not sure what your requirement is, can you provide all cases document and expected result...

Comment: If "consider" is false don't use it for the calculation of main_recom. Only if "consider" is true use it for calculation of main_recom.

Comment: I am not sure what is the requirement here, is the current query give you the correct result or the wrong result and what is the expected?

Comment: Added programmatic code for same.

Comment: see this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FvX2lz1BTN3).